# NDK- convert a negative double number into uint32_t got zero

Tags: c, android-ndk

Sample code is like this.

```
{
    uint32_t x;
    double y;
    y = -1;            // any negative number;
    x = (uint32_t)(y);
    print_log("%u", x);// here, x will be outputed, and it's 0;
}
```

Why will x be 0?

I run the same code in linux-gcc, the result is different.

Comment: The cast is unnecessary; `y = x;` will do the same conversion implicitly. `%u` requires an argument of type `unsigned int` (assuming `print_log` behaves like `printf`). To print a `uint32_t` value, you can use `print_log("%lu", (unsigned long)x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `double` value `-1.0` is outside the range of `uint32_t`.

Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to an unsigned integer type has well-defined behavior. The result is wrapped to the range of the target type (reduced modulo MAX+1, where MAX is the maximum value of the target type).

Converting an out-of-range floating-point value to an integer type has undefined behavior. It's not surprising that the result varies from one system to another. In principle, it could even crash your program.

Once you decide what result you want given an input of `-1.0`, you can figure out how to generate that result without undefined behavior.

Comment: Thx for reply. In my program, I want to calculate the difference between two double numbers. The value should be positive, however, it becomes negative caused by another bug. So I wonder why the value is different between linux-gcc and NDK. And now, I think I should cast the value into int32_t first, then cast into uint32_t.

Comment: I suggest computing the difference as a `double` and then testing whether it's negative.